# replicating an array and storing it in another array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have

```
string[] a = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
```

I want to create a second array and have it store *3 what array `a` has.

So the second array would look like:

```
string[] b = {"1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5"};
```

I was thinking of using `Array.Copy`, but is there another way?

Comment: What is wrong with using `Array.Copy`? Just copy the array to the three segments of the new array.

Comment: What have you tried and where were you stuck? What problem did you reach in order to start thinking you should explore a different way of doing that?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, but sometimes there are different ways of solving the same problem, so I was asking if there is another way to do it. Sometimes there is a function in MSDN that someone knows which does exactly what you are trying to do without implementing anything else, so I thought someone might know a method that replicates an array into another without any external logic or code.

Comment: Use a `List<string>` and AddRange

Comment: List<T>  is easier for that kind of maniplations 
 `List<string> aa = new List<string>(new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" });
            aa.AddRange(aa);
            aa.AddRange(aa);
            aa.AddRange(aa);`

Comment: This question has merit, but it would be improved if you gave some desired characteristics for alternatives, rather than just seeking a list of equivalent approaches. (For example, you might want an alternative that's more flexible, more compact, more readable, or more performant.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below sample performs worse than use of Array.Copy--it's more just playing with ways of accomplishing what you ask.  The final result is obtained with a very simple looking call of `string[] newArray = a.ArrayRepeat(3);`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ArrayRepeat
{
    public static class ArrayHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Repeater<T>(this T[] a, int reps)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++)
            {
                foreach (var item in a)
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }

        public static T[] ArrayRepeat<T>(this T[] a, int reps)
        {
            return a.Repeater<T>(reps).ToArray();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] a = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
            string[] newArray = a.ArrayRepeat(3);

            var pressKeyToExit = Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fun LINQ statement which gets your desired output:

```
b = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).SelectMany(p => a).ToArray();
```

Comment: Its correct, but dirty. Sometimes it's better to write some more lines of code, but have better readability.

Comment: It's a little harder to read, especially for anyone not familiar with LINQ extension methods, but this would be a decent solution for replicating an array *n* number of times (i.e. if the value of "3" is not fixed). I'd probably wrap it in a convenience function to make its purpose a little more clear. :)

Comment: @PawelMaga Yep.  I'd agree.  However, the question was "Is there another way?".  I'm simply giving an example.

Comment: Also, this is neither here nor there, but I wish the API declared InclusiveRange and ExclusiveRange functions, whose parameters were the range bounds. (start, count) just seems unintuitive. :P

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that is not hackish, seems clean, and is maybe even useful, although it still will not perform as well as Array.Copy:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace RepeatArray
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] a = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
            string[] newArray = Enumerable.Repeat(a, 3).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();

            var pressKeyToExit = Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I should give props to @cmcquillan.  I was trying to figure out how to get around the quirkiness of his `SelectMany(p => x)` which just discards `p`.  The idea comes from him, however.